# Run time error 438.Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: vba, ms-access-2013

I am getting this error as seen in screenshot. It was working fine earlier. When we click on debug mode it points to line highligted in yellow. Would appreciate if anyone can help.The line to which it points.
[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5zTr.png)

[The code line to which it points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4Blf.png)

Please find below code:-

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See [mcve].

Comment: What type of control is `pgbSetup1` ? Does it even have a `Max` property?

Comment: Pictures of your code are **useless** to people who want to assist you by stepping through the code and seeing what it is doing wrong.  Why should volunteers spend time retyping it (and hopefully not making typos as they do so!) when it is so easy for you to just copy/paste the code itself into the question.  Please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46121064/edit) to include the code.

Comment: when the code stops at the line, right click `Coll_Docs` and select `add watch` then click `ok`.  the watch window should show the details of the `Coll_Docs` object ... does it have a `Count` property ?

Comment: Now added the code..Can you all please help.and regarding count property I checked it's there

Comment: Hi @YowE3K now added the code .can you please help

Comment: @braX pgbSetup1 is a bar which represents the progress of importing files

Comment: @ShubhamSwarup I think you must have missed clicking "Save" after adding the code to the question.  (I've done that sort of thing a few times myself, so I know how easy it is to make that mistake.)

Answer (score 1):

A Collection does have a Count property, so that leaves you with the faulty "Max" property which no form control has.

Comment: Do you think IF I comment out this and next line will it make much difference in program logic. I know it would be hard to judge from the screenshot. Actually this code is present in other system so I can add the whole function by Monday.Forms!MASTERCOCKPIT!pgbSetup1.Value=0

Comment: When I comment out this line it showed error on next line
Forms!MASTERCOCKPIT!pgbSetup1.Value=0.
On monday I can try to comment out both lines and see if it works but before that wanted to know whether it will alter the logic?

Comment: Hard to tell. We have very little idea of what your code is supposed to do.